# webclient retrieve() vs exchangeToMono() nothing working for this use case

Tags: java, spring-webflux, webclient

API (Name it as api-1) has following property -

1. For 2XX it can return body
2. For 5XX it doesn’t return body

In another API (api-2), Our requirement is if api-1 status code is 2XX return “ABC” else return “XYZ” from webclient call, So we don’t wanted to consume response body in either cases.

Which one should work retrieve() or exchangeToMono() ?

When I use retrieve() I couldn’t return ABC or XYZ based on http response. If I use exchangeToMono() I was getting InvalidStateException with following message “The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a response.”

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: dont describe your code, post your code, with error messages, requests logs, steps to reproduce. Voted to close, needs debugging details. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially the `Help others reproduce the problem` section.

Comment: @Toerktumlare For next queries I will ensure I will add more details. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach.

```
String result = client
        .get()
        .uri("http://localhost:8080/endpoint")
        .retrieve()
        .toBodilessEntity()
        .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, e -> Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(e.getStatusCode()).build()))
        .map(entity -> entity.getStatusCode().isError() ? "error" : "ok")
        .block();
```

`result` is equal to `ok` when the request is completed successfully, and `error` otherwise.

You can change the condition in `map` if you want to return `error` only on 5xx exceptions.

**EDIT:** Or as Toerktumlare mentioned in his comment, you can use `onStatus` to omit an exception.

```
String result = client
        .get()
        .uri("http://localhost:8080/endpoint")
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, e -> Mono.empty())
        .toBodilessEntity()
        .map(entity -> entity.getStatusCode().isError() ? "error" : "ok")
        .block();
```

Comment: or you use the `onStatus` function which is made for this purpose instead of mapping yourself https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve

Comment: @geobreze I must say sorry I forgot to mention this is post request. And I was using HttpEntity for passing body&headers (.uri("http://localhost:8080/endpoint", httpentity)). When I removed it and passed body using .bodyValue() and headers using .header() then it fixed that issue for me.